# Prevent ComboBox in DataGridView from opening and closing instantly in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, dropdown

I have a C# WinForms application, and I succeed in filtering ComboBox items by writing any part of its items and pressing enter after inputing the text part, using this code:

```
        private void detailsGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
            DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            if (comboBox != null)
            {
                comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                comboBox.PreviewKeyDown += ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown;
            }
        }

        private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyCode & e.KeyData) == Keys.Return)
            {
                if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    e.IsInputKey = true;
                    ((ComboBox)sender).DataSource = accounts
                        .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(((ComboBox)sender).Text))
                        .ToList();
                    ((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I encountered a problem in line **((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true** where the list was dropping and closing instantly.

I noticed while debugging that KeyDown event raised twice so I tried a flag variable to check the second raise and cancel, but wasn't useful.
I tried many other approaches like:

- Adding line comboBox.PreviewKeyDown -= ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown; **(with minus)**, before plus line.
- Using each of KeyDown and PreviewKeyDown event listeners.

But the list still closing instantly after it had appeared.

What is the right approach in this context?

**Edit:**

I noticed that when I remove condition line **if ((e.KeyCode & e.KeyData) == Keys.Return)**

The function not work correctly but also the dropdown list stay open.

Comment: Try to set the focus to the ComboBox prior to displaying its dropdown. `((ComboBox)sender).Focus()`

Comment: Not useful, and causing a problem if no items matches.

Comment: You may try the standard KeyDown event here and try setting handled = true. I assume it will stop weird drop down behavior but may prevent also that the selected value will be propagated to the grid itself but you will find out when trying.

Comment: Just a side note: You can simplify `var comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox; if (comboBox != null)` to `if (e.Control is ComboBox comboBox)`.

Comment: You may also look at if EditingControlShowing is called again in this case for the second KeyDown. What i have in mind is that when the "Down-Phase" (i have a problem finding the right wording here) for the key hasn't ended yet it will also be caught by the grid cell after the editor has closed and triggers reopening the editor again (actually a new editor instance if i recall correctly).

Comment: @Ralf I need to use **IsInputKey = true** because DataGridView uses Enter key to EndEdit and I don't wan't to end edit before accept a correct item, I used previewKey because of KeyEventArgs hasn't IsInputKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a separate method for handling filter, and another method for handling KeyDown issue, this is the code:

```
        private void detailsGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
            DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (e.Control is ComboBox comboBox)
            {
                comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

                comboBox.KeyDown += ComboBox_KeyDown;
                comboBox.PreviewKeyDown += ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown;
            }
        }

        private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, 
            PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyCode & e.KeyData) == Keys.Enter)
                if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem == null)
                    e.IsInputKey = true;
        }

        private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyCode & e.KeyData) == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = e.Handled = true;
                    ((ComboBox)sender).DataSource = accounts
                        .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(((ComboBox)sender).Text))
                        .ToList();
                    ((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Anyone can test this easily, its valid for any project.